# Couldn't load symbols in windows 10 mobile version 10.0.10166.0 app crashes after splash

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, debug-symbols, windows-10-mobile

Debug symbols aren't loading while deploying the App in windows 10 mobile OS version 10.0.10166.0. Tried selecting the Microsoft Symbol Server option and also added environment variable `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` with value `symsrv*symsrv.dll*f:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` but no use. I think it's the issue with the mismatch between SDK version 10.0.10240.0 and the mobile OS version 10.0.10166.0. Please help by giving any clue or suggestion. I have made new project in c++ and even got this issue there. Only c# project deploys without any issue but my project is of c++.

This is my output if needed:

> 'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\InstantHousecallRemoteSup.InstantHousecallVS.Debug_ARM.Zahid\SpecialistMetro.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32legacy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d2d1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\PROGRAMS\WINDOWSAPPS\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.23019.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vccorlib140d_app.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\PROGRAMS\WINDOWSAPPS\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.23019.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msvcp140d_app.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'SpecialistMetro.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\PROGRAMS\WINDOWSAPPS\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.23019.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\concrt140d_app.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   The thread 0x768 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
>   The program '[4892] SpecialistMetro.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
>   The program '[2752] ApplicationFrameHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Microsoft doesn't upload PDBs for all Insider preview Builds.

Comment: Then where could i get my required PDBs?

Comment: good question. Ask Microsoft if they upload them.